# Подскажите методы для работы с html файлом из js

Tags: javascript

**Предыстория**

Извините за столь простой и возможно "глупый" вопрос, однако я немного путаюсь в тоннах информации в сети и чтобы не перечитывать всё прошу у вас подсказку.

Мне необходимо попрактиковаться (а откровенно говоря научиться) работать с элементами свёрстанного макета, и для этого необходимо знать о чём именно читать и собственно какие методы использовать. И конечно я буду делать это последовательно и детально, однако сейчас есть небольшая задача которую нужно решить.

Задача заключается в том, что необходимо сделать след. страничку - [клик](http://todomvc.com/examples/react/#/)
своими силами на чистом JS, как получится главное чтобы было похоже и был такой же функционал. Вопрос мой в том, что мне необходим список нужных методов с которыми я буду учиться взаимодействовать. Для индикации элемента я уже использую `document.getElementById('id').value.trim()`трим чтобы исключить пробелы (ну вы и так знаете), далее я умею создавать функцию по клику на кнопку или мышку, и выводить захваченный текст с помощью `document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = text`.

---

**Вопросы**

В моей вёрстке я создал инпут с вводом и под ним список, сделал кнопку закрытия фонтассомом и скрыл элемент списка (мой template).

Мне нужны методы, которые позволят:

1) клонировать мой шаблон списка;
2) выставлять этого клона с добавлением класса (в кот. будет убран `display:none`) и кратко как это делается;
3) метод удаления этих Li-шек (которые будут добавлены при вводе информации в инпут).

Большое спасибо!

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/ - смотрите сразу "часть 2". Удобно тем, что не надо долго шариться по сайту, всё разложено в одном месте.

Comment: Объясните, что за `фонтассом`? Исправьте заголовок вопроса, чтобы он отображал суть вопроса, например: методы для работы с тегом `<template>`. Уберите воду из тела вопроса, т.к. вам явно отвечают не то, что вы ожидаете.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь минимальный рабочий пример (с мелкими косяками), но я сильно не заморачивался с точностью. Вам придется еще сверху много чего добавить. Поэтому этот код годится только на "подсмотреть и написать своё с нуля".

( [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/sr94fvLn/) )

```js
var check = document.querySelector('.check'); /*серая галочка слева от инпута*/
var firstClick = 1; /* в логическом контексте 1 == true, 0 == false */
check.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox');
  if (firstClick) { // Будет true
    this.classList.add('active'); // this указывает на кликнутый элемент
    for (var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
      checkbox[i].classList.add('active');
    } 
    // При первом клике (когда до этого галки вручную могут быть через раз включены или нет)
    // Добавляем активный класс на все чекбоксы без разбора
    firstClick = 0;
  } else {
    // А на следующих кликах условие уже не выполнится - пойдет переключение.
    this.classList.toggle('active');
    for (var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
      checkbox[i].classList.toggle('active');
    }
  }
});

var todo = document.getElementById('todo-list');
var bubu = document.getElementById('bubu');

bubu.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.code == "Enter" && this.value.length) { 
    // Если this.value.length будет 0, это false
    todo.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<li class="li"><div class="checkbox"></div><div class="delete">X</div><div class="txt">' + this.value + '</div></li>');
    this.value = "";
    check.style.display = "block"; // Показываем серую галочку
    firstClick = 1;
  }
});

var prevClick; // Для хранения времени и отслеживания двойного клика
todo.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var target = e.target; // Кликнутый элемент
  if (target.className.match(/delete/)) {
    target.parentNode.outerHTML = ""; // Удаляем родительский элемент (крестик лежал внутри него).
    return; // return прерывает выполнение функции.
  }
  if (target.className.match(/checkbox/)) {
    target.classList.toggle('active');
 var act = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox.active');
 var chbx = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox');
    // Это уже мелкие заморочки. Проверка - если общее количество отмеченных
    // Совпадает с кол-вом чекбоксов - делаем серую галочку темнее, иначе - светлее.
 if( chbx.length === act.length ){
   check.classList.add('active');
 } else {    
   check.classList.remove('active');
 }
    firstClick = 1;
    return;
  }
  var now = Date.now(); 
  if ( target.className.match(/txt/) && ( now - prevClick < 1000)) { // Если от предыдущего клика прошло менее 1 сек.
    // Существует и событие dblclick, но мне показалось так легче.
    // Тем более, можно управлять скоростью двойного клика.
    
    target.contentEditable = true; 
    // А еще показалось, что будет легче делать блок редактируемым, чем создавать в этом месте textarea
    
    getSelection().collapseToEnd(); 
    // Это чтобы от двойного клика текст не выделился и случайно не удалили нажатием кнопки.
    target.focus();
  }
  prevClick = now;
});

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.contentEditable == "true") {
    return;
  }
  var x = document.querySelector('.txt[contentEditable]');
  if (x) {
    x.removeAttribute('contentEditable');
    // Для div нет разницы, какое там значение у contenteditable... если оно есть
    // - будет работать. Значит нужно убрать именно атрибут.
  }
});
```

```css
.relative {
  position: relative;
}

.bubu { /* Основной инпут */
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #222;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 40px;
  outline: none;
  width: 400px;
}

.bubu::placeholder {
  color: #ddd;
  font-style: italic;
}

.check { /* Блок для серой галочки слева от инпута */
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 21px;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden; /* Это чтобы галочка была обрезана с краев */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 0;
}

.check::after { /* Сама галочка */
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: -1px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 3px solid #ccc;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.check.active::after { /* делаем галку чуть темнее, когда добавлен активный класс */
  border-color: #666;
}

#todo-list { /* Общий ul блок */
  width: 445px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.li {
  position: relative; /* Это чтобы удержать внутренние абсолютные блоки
  иначе они будут убегать за рамки li */
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 0 15px 50px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  color: #333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: default;
}

.checkbox { /* круглая серая рамка будущего чекбокса */
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 15px;
}

.checkbox::after { /* Скрытая галочка чекбокса */
  display: none;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #6aa;
  border-right: 2px solid #6aa;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  width: 5px;
  height: 15px;
  left: 8px;
  top: 3px;
}

/* Показываем галочку и подкрашиваем рамку, когда он будет включен */
.checkbox.active::after {
  display: block;
}

.checkbox.active {
  border-color: #9cc;
}

.delete { /* Кнопки-крестики удаления */
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 15px;
  font-family: 'tahoma';
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #d40;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div[contentEditable] {
  padding: 13px 0;
  margin: -13px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #555;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: white;
}

.checkbox.active ~ .txt {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  <input class="bubu" id="bubu" placeholder="What needs to be done?">
  <div class="check"></div>
</div>
<ul id="todo-list"></ul>
```

P.s. можете еще поискать:

• Делегирование Событий

• Регулярные выражения... В целом - полезная штука. Хотя тут они использованы только в match, для определения, есть ли у элемента указанный класс. Это не лучший способ, но здесь прокатывает.

• matches(), closest()

• CSS-селекторы. Они активно используются в `querySelector(...)`. У меня в коде все переключения-галочки написаны на div, но в вашей ссылке они сделаны через настоящие чекбоксы и label... Есть полезный селектор `.class:checked` - находит именно отмеченный чекбокс с этим классом. Так, одной кнопкой скрывая или удаляя все отмеченные, в моём коде можно было достать их через

`document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox.active');`

или, для реальных чекбоксов:

`document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox:checked');`

Answer (score 1):

Пройдите, например, вот эти уроки - http://code.mu/tasks/javascript/base/osnovy-yazyka-javascript-dlya-novichkov.html (там есть как практические задачи, так и теория). Думаю это даст Вам достаточно хороший базис.